# Get all files form a group folder?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

After long struggling, I just can't do the most simple and obvious thing, to read all files/photos from **a specific folder(group)** that I create in my app by "Add new group" menu on the left side of Xcode.

I have tried so many pieces of code, all tells me there is no such folder, but the folder is there in front of me.

```
     if let path = Bundle.main.resourcePath {

        let imagePath = path + "/Artworks"
        let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: imagePath)
        let fileManager = FileManager.default

        let properties = [URLResourceKey.localizedNameKey,
                          URLResourceKey.creationDateKey, URLResourceKey.localizedTypeDescriptionKey]

        do {
            let imageURLs = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: url as URL, includingPropertiesForKeys: properties, options:FileManager.DirectoryEnumerationOptions.skipsHiddenFiles)

            print("image URLs: \(imageURLs)")
            // Create image from URL
            //var myImage =  UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: imageURLs[0])!)

        } catch let error1 as NSError {
            print(error1.description)
        }
    }
```

> ```
>  The file “Artworks” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file."
> ```

What else should I do to simply be able to arrange lots of photos inside a group folder and read only from that folder all the photos names/urls ?

EDIT :
Printing the path gives me :

```
/Users/me/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/673ED39D-61D6-4F2D-BAC9-3EC7C4AC2089/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7CDD3B62-B04O-4A48-8716-D83F6EDA5689/appName.app/Artworks
```

Comment: let imagePath = path + "assets/Artworks" doesn't appear valid.

Comment: @ElTomato Thanks, sorry, please check my edit, I copied the wrong code, this is the one I use.

Comment: It gives me no errors, just a warning there is no such directory, so how should I do that to read from a group ?

Comment: Why don't you just print imagePath and see if the path is valid?

Comment: @ElTomato it says "The file “appName.appArtwork” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file" ,  but why does it looks for appArtwork and not Artwork ?

Comment: Please also see my edit about printing the path

Comment: Do I have to copy this folder to the appbundle? just creating it is not enough ?

Comment: Yellow folders in Xcode do not translate to actual folders within your app bundle. All of your files are in the root of the app bundle. Look inside the .app file to see its contents when built.

Answer (score 4):

You have to create folder reference while adding the images in Xcode project.

[![Folder reference][1]][1]

Once folder reference is created, it will look like below.

[![Project navigator][2]][2]

The files can be read using the below code.

```
let directory = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "iPad", ofType: nil, inDirectory: "1")
let contentsArray = try? FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: directory!)
```

The contentsArray will have a count of 7 in this case.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLkyD.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Toizp.png

Answer (score -2):

Actually, amazingly, for 2 days no one could tell me the real issue here.
Creating a **group**, is completely different from **dragging** a folder into the project.

For some reason, with Apple, its always complicated with files. I have to figure out the NOT so intuitive approach that a group that looks like a folder, is nothing but a nice way to look at something, and **will not create a real folder accessible by the file manager.**

Simply put, create a *blue* folder outside Xcode and drag it in.

Comment: Huh? @arunGJ posted their answer an hour after you posted your question and you posted this answer 15 minutes after that. What took 2 days?